# Getting multiple values from a function without creating a variables in LUA

Tags: lua, love2d

Is there any way to get several values from a function without creating variables for it?

```
local major, minor, revision, codename = love.getVersion() -- Get current LÖVE version as a string.
```

So instead of making four different variables (or array) we'll use something that will just return a value you need.

```
get( love.getVersion(), 0 ) -- Will return the first value (major).
```

I read somewhere that I can use square brackets and tried`love.getVersion()[1]` but it says "Attempt to index a number value."

Comment: I think you can use underscores for the values you don't need. As in `local major, _, _, _ = love.getVersion()`

Comment: `local minor = select(2, love.getVersion())`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the sake of example let's assume that `love.getVersion()` is defined as follows:

```lua
function love.getVersion ()
   return 1, 2, 3, "four"
end
```

#### Using `select(index, ...)`:

If `index` is number then `select` returns all arguments after argument index of `index`. Consider:

```lua
print("A:", select(3, love.getVersion()))
local revision = select(3, love.getVersion())
print("B:", revision)
```

outputs:

```
A:  3   four
B:  3
```

In case of doubts - [Reference Manual - `select`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-select).

#### Using a table wrapper:

You have mentioned trying `love.getVersion()[0]`. That's *almost* it, but you first need to wrap the values returned into an actual table:

```lua
local all_of_them = {love.getVersion()}
print("C:", all_of_them[4])
```

outputs:

```
C:  four
```

In case you want to do it in one line (in the spirit of "without creating a variables") you need to wrap the table in parentheses, too:

```lua
print("D:", ({love.getVersion()})[1])
```

outputs:

```
D:  1
```

#### Using the `_` variable:

Coming from the other languages you can just assign values you are not interested in with `_` (nobody will notice we create a variable if it is a short flat line), as in:

```lua
local _, minor = love.getVersion()
print("E:", minor)
```

outputs:

```
E:  2
```

Please note that I skipped any following `_` in the example (no need for `local _, minor, _, _`).

Comment: Fantastic! I didn't even expect more detailed answer as this. Definitely respect!

Comment: The table wrapping method is very slow, by the way.

Comment: @younyokel, oh yes, but it's still a valid option :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the function signature: [https://love2d.org/wiki/love.getVersion] which just returns multiple value, if understand to achieve like what you are asking for, you can have wrapper around getVersion to have lua table returned either like below or in array format

```
local function getVersion()
 local meta_data = {minor_version = "0.1", major_version = "1"}
 return meta_data
end

local res = getVersion()
print ("minor_version: ", res['minor_version'])
print ("major_version: ", res['major_version'])
```