# Functions that return multiple values Lua

Tags: lua

My question is on functions like `pairs()`. Functions like this return multiple values like this:

```
function foo()
     x = bar()
     y = x*2
     return x, y
end

x, y = foo()
```

Is there a way to get just the second value without bothering with the first? Why would this be preferable to simply returning a table?

*It seemed to me like this question probably already existed on this site, but I couldn't find it. Sorry if it's a duplicate.*

Comment: You were right: [Getting multiple values from a function without creating a variables in LUA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379596/getting-multiple-values-from-a-function-without-creating-a-variables-in-lua) the context and naming is slightly different, probably that's why you didn't find it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Using Underscores

It is idiomatic in Lua to discard unwanted values by using an underscore:

```
_, y = foo()
```

When you encounter something like `x, y = foo()` in source code, you expect that both `x` and `y` will be used, but the underscore convention communicates the intent that the value assigned to `_` is not needed and will not be used.

This is the method that seems most common, and is most used in *Programming in Lua*. This idiom shows up frequently in loops using iterators. For example, the `ipairs` iterator function returns both an index and a value, but you may only be interested in the value. The usual idiom for this is:

```
for _, v in ipairs(t) do
   -- some stuff using v
end
```

### Using `select`

The [`select`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-select) function takes an initial argument which may be a number or the string `"#"`, and an arbitrary number of additional arguments. When the initial argument is a number N, *all* additional arguments starting from the Nth are returned. Since Lua discards unassigned values, this can be used to select a single argument:

```
y = select(2, foo())
```

OP example function returns two values, but for functions that return more than two values:

```
y, z = select(2, bar())
```

and

```
_, y, z = bar()
```

both assign the second and third return values of `bar` to `y` and `z`, respectively.

The underscore method is less verbose, and more clear in my opinion. Using `select` also adds the overhead of an additional function call. There are cases in which using `select` makes more sense, e.g., when you want to programmatically select a return value. Which method you choose is largely a matter of taste.

### Wrapping Return Values in a Table

Sometimes it makes sense to wrap multiple return values in a table, but as a general rule this is a bad idea. Wrapping values in a table inside of the function means that a new table must be created, and this takes time; in a loop this can mean significantly slower code.

You might have a case where it helps clarify your code to return a table, e.g., a function `stats` that returns the mean, median, and mode of some data. In this case you might want to collect those statistics in a table instead of returning them as separate values.

If the values returned from a function make sense as a table, return a table.

### Final Thoughts

Use the method that makes your code the most clear. In my opinion the underscore method is the best way to do this unless you have a good reason to use one of the other approaches.

Comment: Note that you can also do `_x, y = foo()`; the `_` indicates that `_x` is unused, but you're still giving it a meaningful name so the user knows *what* it is you're discarding.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the builtin `select`-Function for that:

```lua
function test()
    return "Hello", "World"
end

local x = select(2, test())
print(x) -- prints World
```

This is also shown in the [documentation](https://www.lua.org/pil/5.2.html)

Answer (score 1):

#### Hello

> I like to return a table for multiple results.
> Like debug.getinfo() or other functions.

```
several_results=function() return {os.date(), os.time()} end

tab=several_results()

print(#tab) -- How many keys?

print(tab[1], tab[2]) -- For both values

print(tab[2]) -- Get value only from second key

print(tab[#tab]) -- For the value of last key

-- And a simple loop...
for incr=1,#tab do print(tab[incr]) end
```

> But you have to care about the Len ( # ) of a table that depends on the content.
> Keys that are named and can be accessed with a dot are not countable.

```
tab={}
tab['name']='Arthur Dent'
print(#tab, tab.name)
-- puts out: 0 Arthur Dent
-- Same with Zero and negative numbers
tab={[0]=0,[-1]=-1}
print(#tab, tab[0], tab[-1])
-- puts out: 0 0 -1
```